# How to connect Flask application to SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, flask

I have a SQL Server which I need to connect my Flask app. What are the steps to doing this connection? Do I need to make a separate login in SQL Server for this? Do I need to run SQL in localhost or something first? I'm not very familiar with SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Flask SQLAlchemy then you can set the url of your SQL server to the `app.config['SQLACHLEMY_DATABASE_URI']` Variable.